# How to set the value to null through rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

how to make a column value to null through model in ruby on rails? For example, I have a `checkbox` called `'include_on_epc'` and the `textbox` called `'removal_reason'`.

If the checkbox is checked, I want to set the value of the textbox should be NULL in database.

I tried the following, its not working.

```
class Emm::Rrr::Result < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :no_removal_reason_when_including_on_epc

  private
  def no_removal_reason_when_including_on_epc
    if include_on_epc == 1
      self.removal_reason == nil
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two issues here.

1. As Jakob pointed out, `self.removal_reason == nil` compares `removal_reason` to `nil`, and you want to *set* `removal_reason` to `nil`. Therefore `self.removal_reason = nil` is definitely what you want here.
2. If `include_on_epc` is a `boolean` column, comparing to `1` is not going to work. You probably want a simple `if include_on_epc` because its values are likely `true` or `false`, not `1` or `0`, and in Ruby `1 != true`.

Comment: Cool... Its worked. Your second point is worked!... Thanks for the detailed answer to update myself. Thank you so much Andy....

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `self.removal_reason == nil` should be `self.removal_reason = nil`. You want assignment, not comparison in that line I guess. ;-)

Comment: `include_on_epc` might be "1" not 1. Try `if include_on_epc.to_i == 1` or check against a string and see if that makes any difference